# Is there any preferred direction for the electron spin?

Tags: quantum-spin

The electron id usually defined as a -1/2 (spin-down) particle , implying that p and L vectors point in opposite direction. Is that just an arbitrary convention or is that a basic/preferred orentation of S? When electrons are shot by a gun in a tube, is the direction of the spin just random?

In an atom electrons are paired, but is their spin exactly aligned (anti/)parallel with the axis of p?

Comment: what is the p vector?

Comment: @SeñorO, usaually, p is momentum

Comment: electron spin is a quantum effect and should not be visualized classically

Comment: @SAKhan, even so , even as an intrinsic property, it must have a direction. Can you have angular momentum without a definite direction? If there were no direction, how can you have electrons paired by opposite (up/down) direction? QM can't have it both ways.

Comment: Hi. QM in fact has it all ways in pure systems before some kind of interaction happen, a measurement for example. If you have an isolated electron, then it may be with spin "up" or "down", and linguistically it is in both states- in at least probabilistic understanding . It will definitely be at one of those states after interaction.

Comment: @SAKhan in what way was he visualizing it classically?

Comment: He says that p vector ...which would mean a momentum associated with a particle orbiting around a point.

Comment: @SAKhan, does QM deny it has momentum and angular momentum and orbital momentum and angular momentum? If so, how do you explain fine structure ?

Comment: I maybe did not understand the question. QM does not deny these dyanmical variables however to picture them in classical terms specially for small quantum numbers would mean taking a wrong view. For instance an S state of zero angular momentum if taken as resulting from the motion of a point particle would be an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course there is a preferred spin direction, because electrons have a magnetic moment.  Any unpaired electrons will align with the local
magnetic field (weakly, but electron paramagnetic resonance relies
on generating a signal from this).  In spectroscopy, the associated
energy-level splitting is called
the Zeeman effect.

Two electrons in (for instance) a 3S orbital will pair, but in shells that have empty states, electrons (by Hund's rule) will usually align
with each other.   That alignment, too, is a spin directional preference.

Ferromagnetism and antiferromagnetism are more complicated, but are
alignments of electron spins.

Comment: Thanks, can you describe how the (first) electron aligns joining a proton or a Helium ion?

Comment: In the case of a proton (which has its own magnetic moment), the spin-spin interaction causes a hyperfine splitting of the spectrum lines; this is such a small energy difference, it only matters in very cold environments, but space IS cold, and contains hydrogen.    There's a good discussion here <http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_12.html>

Answer (score 0):

[image]In a recent formalism of quantum mechanics,  I have found that $\vec{\sigma}\times\vec{p}=0$.

This formalism is available under request.